# Which random events reset in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I realize that I've probably missed quite a few random events because I usually whizz by on my bike. Now that the main mission is over, I'd like to explore the map but am worried that I've already triggered and missed all the best random events. Which ones reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of them "reset." There are a few that can only be done once, like chasing the bike thief to get the stock payoff and helping the crew member rob whatever he was robbing. The rest are all random events that repeat endlessly.